# Is there a way to set an Aurora writer instance read-only?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

What I *want* to do is `SET global read_only=1` on an AWS Aurora writer instance. Obviously this requires the `SUPER` grant, and I gather from other answers and Aurora documentation that `SUPER` cannot be granted. AFAICT there is no `mysql.rds_*` function that does this, and I can't make out whether there is some parameter group that would allow something like this to be done.

Other than locking individual tables for writes, are there any other options available in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that it needs to be done in a parameter group.

You can either edit your existing parameter group, or copy it to a new one and then edit the parameter group and change `read_only` from `{TrueIfReplica}` to `1`, and then save your changes.

You will be prompted whether to apply the change immediately or in the next maintenance window, but its a very quick change to apply and I am sure you would want to apply it immediately.

Once the change is applied, it will take about 5-10 seconds to take effect.

Comment: Accepting this answer because I think it's most likely to be useful to other people who find this question (but it turns out it's not the answer I need for my situation)

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer.  Would you mind sharing why it does not work for your specific use case?

Comment: Because the latency on parameter group changes (which in testing seem to potentially be up to 30s) is too high for the use case (where we need immediate response). We're opting to temporarily change the user auth credentials as a hack to get that immediate response.

Answer (score 1):

According to AWS Support the 'Read_only' parameter has no effect on Aurora Serverless v1.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v1.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.parameter-groups) says that "some of the changes that you might make to parameters for a particular DB engine type might not apply". 'Read_only' parameter is one of them because it has no effect on Aurora Serverless v1. You still will be able write to your database even after enabling 'Read_only' parameter in parameter group.

The possible solutions could be

1. Use triggers which always rejects the write, for example:

```
create trigger readonly_insert_trigger_table1
    before insert on table1
    for each row
begin
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Table is readonly';
end
```

2. Snapshot (and then restore).